# Loop over json array object

Tags: javascript, json, nested

How do I loop over the json array of objects having below json structure:

```
"ArrayOfAddress": [{
    "address": {
    "country": "US",
    "city":"NewYork"
    },
    "Type": "435473"
},{
    "address":{
        "country":"Germany",
        "city":"abc"
    },
    "Type":"124586"
}
]
```

and access country ,city and type values

Comment: Does what you posted sit inside an object? Is this the structure of the parent array?': `[{ "ArrayOfAddress": [], ...}, ...]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: the above structure is inside another object {"outerArray":[ { "ArrayOfAddresses":[] }] }

Comment: Just use array.forEach(object=>{ })

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're trying to access these properties after storing the json into an object.

```js
a = {"ArrayOfAddress": [{
                "address": {
                    "country": "US",
                    "city":"NewYork"
                },
                "Type": "435473"
            },{
                                   "address":{
                                            "country":"Germany",
                                             "city":"abc"
                                         },
                                    "Type":"124586"

                              }

                 ]}
a.ArrayOfAddress.forEach((val) => {document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += (val.address.country + " " + val.address.city + " "+ val.Type) + "<br/>"})
```

```html
<span id="content"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean?
Do you want the loop to go over every single leaf value? (country:us, city:NY, type:435473, country:germany, city:abc, type:123586)?

Comment: yes I  want to loop over every single leaf value and push them in another array.